# Form not submitted by $(form).submit() subsequently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a server-side form validation. On [submit] button clicked my code adds field **_validate** to the form and sends the form to the server in AJAX mode. On success form should be submitted, but it not happened.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form[action*="#validate"]').on('submit', function(e){
        var $form = $(this);
        var $submit = $form.find('input[type=submit]');
        var $validate = $form.find('input[name=_validate]');
        if ($validate.length>0 && $validate.val()=='success') // already validated
        {
            //e.returnValue = true; it's deprecated
            console.log('validated'); // #2
            return true; // supposed form submit
        }
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($validate.length==0)
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="_validate" value="asking" />');    
            $validate = $form.find('input[name=_validate]');
            var params = $form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                method: $form.attr('method').toLowerCase(),
                data: params
            })
                .then(function(response, statusText, xhrObj){
                    var json = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (json._status!='ok')
                    {
                        // writing messages
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $validate.val('success');
                        $form.attr('action', $form.attr('action').replace('#validate', ''));
                        $form.submit(); // #1
                    }
                }); 

    });
    

});
```

form.submit() marked with **#1** makes subsequest onsubmit call, the script prints **validated** (**#2**) but form woudn't submit - no queries in Net console, no error or warning messages.

Comment: Change your (#1) to `$form[0].submit()` so that it uses the js submit not the jquery one.

Comment: Please add some HTML for testing..

Comment: freedomn-m, $form[0].submit() is not a function. Notably, that submit process started, it prints 'validated' in onsubmit, but still not submitting...

Comment: I figured out that this is Opera-related issue, the code works fine in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a vanilla JavaScript version. As I see it there is no reason not to have the input element (`name="_validate"`) in the form from the beginning. Instead of changing the action attribute on the form you can use the formaction attribute on the submit button.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    let form = e.target;
    let submitter = e.submitter;
    if(form._validate.value == 'success'){
      console.log('validated');
    }else{
      e.preventDefault();
      let data = new FormData(form);
      console.log(submitter.formAction);
      //fetch(submitter.formAction, { // line replaced by dataURI for testing:
      fetch('data:application/json,{"_status":"ok"}', {
        method: form.method,
        data: data
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          if(json._status!='ok'){
            // writing messages
          }else{
            form._validate.value = 'success';
            console.log('Submitting...');
            form.submit();
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="textinput"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="_validate" value=""/>
  <button type="submit" formaction="#validate">Submit</button>
</form>
```